# ng-class within ng-repeat having dynamic ng-model

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am iterating over a array of strings with ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="i in mdsecuritysensorswsize">
```

in there I have a required select with a 'dynamic model'

```
ng-model="valueBag[i+'sizes']"
```

now I want to add a has-error class, if the select is empty (apply bootsrap3 error style)

```
ng-class="{'has-error': myForm.valueBag[i+'sizes'].$invalid, 'has-success': !myForm.valueBag[i+'sizes'].$invalid}"
```

But this doesn't seem to work with such a dynamic ng-model name.

Here is the complete code:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in mdsecuritysensorswsize">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2"
         ng-class="{'has-error': myForm.valueBag[i+'sizes'].$invalid, 'has-success': !myForm.valueBag[i+'sizes'].$invalid}"
         >
      <select class="form-control" required
          ng-options="resText[j] for j in mdsecuritysensorswsizesizes2"
          ng-model="valueBag[i+'sizes']"></select>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: try using `$index` instead of `i` to access you array elements, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21414140/189756)

Comment: Please post the code of the controller.

Comment: if you create your form inputs dynamically, it will be a problem with this code when you try to access `myForm.valueBag[i+'sizes'].$invalid` If you create form inputs dynamically, check out my directive to solve this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455695/angularjs-dynamic-form-field-validation/21457121#21457121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this from the comments did the job:

if you create your form inputs dynamically, it will be a problem with this code when you try to access myForm.valueBag[i+'sizes'].$invalid If you create form inputs dynamically, check out my directive to solve this problem here: stackoverflow.com/questions/21455695/… –  Khanh TO Feb 3 at 10:04

[AngularJS dynamic form field validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455695/angularjs-dynamic-form-field-validation/21457121#21457121)

THX @Khanh TO