# AngularJS: Detecting which checkbox in an ngRepeat is checked/unchecked and calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I think I'm trying to do something relatively simple in Angular but for some reason I can't get my head perfectly around ngClick, ngModel, ngChange or ngChecked to solve it.

I have a whole bunch of repeated checkboxes and when one is checked, a function alerts one thing and when its unchecked, the function alerts a different thing. Here's some pseudo code:

HTML:

```
<div id="topic" ng-repeat="50 times">
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='???' ng-click='myFunc($index)' />
</div>
```

Script:

```
function myFunc(index) {
    if (checkbox == checked) {
      alert('checkbox ' + index + 'checked!');
    }
    else {
      alert('checkbox' + index + 'unchecked!');
    }
}
```

So the problem is I can't figure out how to tell which checkbox in the repeat is checked and when it's unchecked. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle?

Comment: I can't really add a fiddle because I don't know how to do this properly. The fiddle would just be broken. Is something not clear?

Comment: have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21414140/189756)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the help of a controller..

I'd do something like this:

Initialise an empty array of values on the `$scope` and a function to use on change.

```
$scope.checkboxes = [];

$scope.alert = function(index, event){

  alert("checkbox " + index + " is " + $scope.checkbox[index]);

}
```

Bind `ng-model` to `checkboxes[$index]`, then you can use `ng-change` because you have specified a model.

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       ng-model="checkbox[$index]" 
       ng-change="alert($index)">
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fgHOvkIOjoHGa05aMlmd?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Ng-model gets called after ng-click. so you can clear model on ng-click and its done.
nd-model will bing the value after ng-click

Javascript Code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.sunday_workshop.length; i++) {              
                $scope.sunday_workshop[i].flag = false;                 
            }
```

HTML Code:

```
 <div ng-repeat="workshop in sunday_workshop">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sun_workshop" ng-checked="workshop.flag" ng-model="workshop.flag" ng-click="workshop_method('sunday')"> {{workshop.WS_Option}}
```